# How to show or hide div on radiobuttonlist checked without jquery(if Javascript is disable) in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

It works fine with jquery is there any way in mvc where I can fire an event on radiobuttonlist checked that executes server side code and can display or hide div accordingly, thanks in advance/

Comment: You can use the HTML Partial Views, to show different HTML blocks in your by view according some logic, by calling @Html.Partial(<partialViewName>), but I really don't know how to call it from a radiobuttonList event without js. I think you are gonna need to reload the page and show a different partialView.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Guillelon, so when you say I need to reload the page for a different partial view did you mean I need to submit the whole page check if js off and excute my logic accordingly in my httppost  acionresult.

Comment: Yes, the thing is that I don't know how to interact in the client side html objects without using JS. So accordingly what checkbox was selected, you go to the controller again and in the http post do some logic to reload the page again with a different partialView. Let me know ;)